# How to add internal, revision comments to page updates

Tags: comments, admin, revisions

I'm not sure the proper WP parlance for this, but I'd like to add historical comments to submitted page updates for version control purposes or as a supplement to the Revisions Browser. (Something like an additional page attribute to be seen when browsing through historical versions of a page.)

EXAMPLE:

1. Modify page content
2. Enter internal comment about changed content
3. Update page
4. View comments per page revision

*(Yes, I'm using Git for proper version control, but for content updates only captured in the database, I'd like to be able to do something similar to a Git "commit" comment.)*

Currently, I don't see an out-of-the box way to do this, but maybe I've missed something.

Numerous Wordpress Plugin searches and Google searches return results for the common cases of end-user comment management. I'd like something for INTERNAL, HISTORICAL use only.

Any suggestions for a plugin or native option?

Comment: if you want to extend the native WordPress [Revisions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions) you can try find a hook in the wordpress [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/revision.php) `_wp_put_post_revision ` looks like the action to hook into. there are two others `wp_restore_post_revision` and `wp_delete_post_revision`

Answer (score 2):

I've often thought this would make a good feature, though I've never seen a plugin for it. I think the term "comment" is probably throwing off your search. I wouldn't think that this would be stored as a comment internally, but rather as metadata for the post. I did a search for plugins using the term "revision description" instead of revision comment, and I found one plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-revision/

It displays the revision description on the front-end, so it isn't exactly what you were looking for. Also, it only keeps track of the description for the *latest* revision, not older revisions. However, it might still offer some inspiration for someone looking to create a plugin like this.

It does store the revision comment as post metadata, just like I thought. However, there is a problem with this, and that is that post metadata isn't versioned with revisions—which is why it only can keep track of the description for the last revision. But you might be able to use the [WP Post Meta Revisions](https://github.com/adamsilverstein/wp-post-meta-revisions) plugin to version that particular piece of metadata.

(I guess maybe this isn't a real answer, but it is too long for a comment, and I thought that I should post it for posterity. :-)